# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when using $routeparams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Have an angular app with mongodb, express and nodejs. In the app i have a list of flats and want to add "Edit" option for every flat.
This is part of my api.js:

```
api.route('/flats/:id')
  .get(function(req, res){
    Flat.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post){
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(post)
    })
  })
  .put(function(req, res){
    Flat.findById(req.params.id, function(err, flat){
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
      return('TODO POST FLAT WITH ID');
    })
  })
```

This part of code working, and in postman i have an rightly array.
This is part of my routes file:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/flats/:id', {
        controller: 'FlatController',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/edit.html'
      })          
    });
```

Next part - this is a table with all flats. On click i want to open a page with a single flat

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="field in flat.fields">
        {{ field }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-click="flat.showflat(flatone._id)" ng-repeat="flatone in flat.flats">
      <td ng-repeat="field in flat.fields">
        {{ flatone[field] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is part of my controller:

```
angular.module('flatCtrl', ['flatoneService'])
  .controller('FlatController', ['FlatOne', '$filter', '$location', '$timeout', '$interval', '$routeParams', function(FlatOne, $filter, $location, $timeout, $interval, $routeParams){
    vm = this;
    vm.flats = FlatOne.query();
    vm.showflat = function(_id){
      var flatId = _id;
      vm.flatsToEdit = FlatOne.get({id: $routeParams._id});
      $location.url('/flats/edit');
    }
  }])
```

In this controller i have rightly _id, but $routeParams is undefined, and i don't understand why.

This is my service:

```
angular.module('flatoneService', [])
  .factory('FlatOne', function ($resource){
    return $resource('/api/flats/:id', {id:'@_id'}, {
      'update': {method: 'PUT'}
    });
  });
```

In result when i click to the row i have a rightly url, for example http://localhost:3000/flats/55c59f11cbe8d2b4105c149c, and an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. I expect to get app/views/pages/edit.html, but get a html code of my main page.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (native)
    at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:2622
    at Function.m.extend.globalEval (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:2633)
    at m.ajaxSetup.converters.text script (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:26520)
    at Pb (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:18363)
    at x (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:21793)
    at m.ajaxTransport.a.send.b (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:26030)
    at Object.m.ajaxTransport.a.send (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:26134)
    at Function.m.extend.ajax (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:21570)
    at Function.m._evalUrl (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:22649)

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the `FlatOne.get` call, your `$routeParam` should be `$routeParams.id`/ may be you are already passing that parameter to function as `_id` & then change get `id` to `_id` because you have `{id:'@_id'}` in your `$resource`.

```
vm.flatsToEdit = FlatOne.get({_id: _id});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but i still have an $routeParams undefined. In vm.flatsToEdit = FlatOne.get({_id: $routeParams.id}); i have an error: "https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=Error%20in%20resource%20configuration%20for%20action%20%60%7B0%7D%60.%20Expected%20response%20to%20contain%20an%20%7B1%7D%20but%20got%20an%20%7B2%7D&p1=get&p2=object&p3=array"

Comment: @EugeniuszZuev then you should have try `FlatOne.get({_id: _id});`..look at my edit..

Comment: and this doesn't work too, i'm got an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ((

Comment: oh...so why don't you go for it..is there any problem with that too??

Comment: i have ng-click="flat.showflat(flatone._id). When i don't use /:id, after changing location i don't have an id of the element

Answer (score 0):

You're already passing id to show function:

```
ng-click="flat.showflat(flatone._id)"
```

so I think there is no need to use $routeParams:

```
vm.showflat = function(_id){
  var flatId = _id;
  //vm.flatsToEdit = FlatOne.get({id: $routeParams._id});
  vm.flatsToEdit = FlatOne.get({id: _id}); // may be this?
  $location.url('/flats/edit');
}
```

Comment: yes, u're right, but in this case i have an error too. error is on the top. this /:id don't working.

Comment: and if i'm doing something like this, i don't have id after $location.url()